# $agi->get_data suddenly stop with result of "D"

Tags: php, asterisk, voip, agi, phpagi

In PHPAGI for reading digit from user i'm using $agi->get_data

```
$rawInput = $agi->get_data($audio, 5000, 1);
$input = $rawInput['result'];
```

Some users didn't hit any key, but after 2-3 seconds audio playback immediately stops and `$rawInput['result']` show `"D"` as a result!!
Am i doing something wrong? or its Asterisk or PHPAGI bug?

Answer (score 0):

D is valid DTMF digit in extended DTMF format. Valid are 0-9,A-F,*,#

You have do debug dtmf and general debug to see what is really happens.